# How do I get the next identity ID before Submit in Linq-to-Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to get the next identity ID and then log it somewhere.  Only *after* this do I want to call SubmitChanges().

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the `DataContext` in a database transaction and call `SubmitChanges` to write changes to the database within that transaction. This way you can get the auto generated ID while being able to keep the operation transactional:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var tran = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var db = new YourDataContext(con))
        {
            // Setting the transaction is needed in .NET 3.5. 
            // It's a bug in L2S and was fixed in .NET 4.0.
            db.Transaction = tran;

            var entity = new MyEntity();

            db.MyEntities.InsertOnSubmit(entity);

            db.SubmitChanges();

            var id = entity.Id;

            // Do something useful with this id
        }

        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole thing in a transaction, do a SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name') then submit your changes, the commit the transaction.  If you lock the table that should prevent someone else from inserting a record after your SELECT IDENT_CURRENT and before you insert which should give you the correct identity value.

Comment: sounds good, but i need to do all in one tran, without locking(

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the `lastModified` date column in DB and get it,if not and increment the identity column

Other wise better do  `SubmitChanges()` and get the `nextID`